# SwiftUI - Combining autoresizing shapes/paths into a single shape/path

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to create a gradient view in SwiftUI that can dynamically change size, yet remain as a single shape so I can add gradients to it.

I unfortunately have to avoid using fixed sizes in my views/shapes as their sizes depend on their contents.

**Here is the behaviour I am attempting to achieve:**

[image: Desired behaviour]

I am able to get a solid colour across the three text views, by adding a background to each one:

```
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
    Text("Top bar")
        .background(Rectangle().fill(.blue))
    Text("Middle bar with maybe some more content in")
        .background(Rectangle().fill(.blue))
    Text("Bottom bar")
        .background(Rectangle().fill(.blue))
}
```

I'm assuming I need to combine the paths of the three text views, however, as I do not know their sizes beforehand, I cannot use Shape().path(in rect: CGRect) to get the paths to combine. The issue is the same if I try and draw out the path manually to put as the background of the VStack as I do not know the sizes of each of the text views.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

This requires a little bit of verbosity in order to repeat the contents, but it does get the job done:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            Text("Top bar")
            Text("Middle bar with maybe some more content in")
            Text("Bottom bar")
        }
        .background(LinearGradient(colors: [.red, .blue], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
        .mask {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                Text("Top bar")
                    .background(Rectangle().fill(Color.white))
                Text("Middle bar with maybe some more content in")
                    .background(Rectangle().fill(Color.white))
                Text("Bottom bar")
                    .background(Rectangle().fill(Color.white))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! If there's no other way of doing it, this is a nice simple way of doing it. My only thought is that performance may suffer a little bit if any of the bars have some more content added to them (e.g. images, more text, buttons, etc.).

Comment: I don't think performance will be an issue -- SwiftUI is pretty good about that. It's more the annoyance of adding the modifiers like this individually